# How to make top node to be centered?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

I'm having problems fine tuning the picture. It's almost as it should be but "node a" isn't really centered as it's too much to the right and the rest is too much below it. Could you help, please?

[image]

The code I'm using is:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Coordinate for centering 'a'
        \coordinate (center) at (0,0);

        % Texts without boxes
        \node[](a) at (center) {\textbf{Exploitation of the error of rationality}};
        \node[below left=1.5cm and -1.5cm of a, align=center] (b) {Motivated Influence};
        \node[below right=1.5cm and -2.75cm of a, align=center] (c) {Cognitive disability};

        % Boxes
        \node[draw, below=0.15cm of b.south, text width=6.3cm, align=center] (d)  {\textbf{Psyops Domain}
            \linebreak
            \linebreak Action on beliefs
            \linebreak Distorted perceptions
            \linebreak Cultural illusion
            \linebreak Anxiety and fears
            \linebreak Personality weaknesses and strengths
            \linebreak Repression};
        \node[draw, right=0.5cm of d, text width=6.3cm, align=center] (e) {\textbf{Cognitive Warfare Domain}
            \linebreak
            \linebreak Action on cognitions
            \linebreak Sensory and perceptive overflow
            \linebreak Attentional saturation
            \linebreak Tunneling of attention
            \linebreak Errors of judgment
            \linebreak Cognitive biases};

        % Arrows
        \draw[-stealth] (a) -- (b);
        \draw[-stealth] (a) -- (c);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Differences Between Cognitive Warfare and PSYOPS (Including, in Broad Terms, Actual Psychological Operations and Other Non-Kinetic Actions such as Influence Operations and Civil-Military Cooperation)}
    \label{fig:figexplot}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Use the same horizontal distance for placing `b` (`-1.5cm`) and `c` (`-2.75cm`) and not different ones. And place `e` below of `c` for consistency.

Comment: Thank You! That solved the issue!